# Cast from generic to generic

Tags: c#, generics, casting

In a nutshell I'm trying to get this code working:

```
class it<X>
{
    X[] data;
    int pos;

    public Y get<Y>()
    {
        return (Y) data[pos];
    }
}
```

Basically, I have lots of arrays of different primitives that needs to be processed another place as different primitives. The former code won't compile because the compiler doesn't know what X and Y is. The following, does, however:

```
    public Y get<Y>()
    {
        return (Y) (object) data[pos];
    }
```

However, then I get runtime exceptions like:

```
InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.
it[System.Double].get[Single]()
```

Which seems silly because C# obviously has a cast between floats and doubles (and other primitives). I'm guessing it has something to do with boxing and such, but I'm pretty new to C# so I don't really know - I guess I'm used to C++ templates. Note that a conversion between X and Y always exists - can I tell the compiler this, some way?

Comment: I know this was a quick example for SO, but you should try to follow the [C# naming guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). `get<Y>` should be `Get`, `it<T>` should be `It<T>`. Also not part of the naming guidlines but in my personal opinion private fields should be preceded by a `_` for `_data` and `_pos` so you can tell them apart from method parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Although, as always, consistency between persons and code in a larger project is often preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Convert`'s `ChangeType`-method:

```
public Y get<Y>()
{
    return (Y)Convert.ChangeType(data[pos], typeof(Y));
}
```

It might also be a good idea to add some [generic constraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) to your class and method to ensure only primitives can be passed:

```
class it<X> where X : struct

public Y get<Y>() where Y : struct
```